# Do I need hidden decking fasteners on both sides of a joist?

Tags: deck, fastener

I am thinking about using the below fasteners with wood planks. Do I need them on both sides of the joist?

[image]

Update: Deck framing layout below (height is 46") House located at the south east corner of the picture (along that side of the deck)
[image]

Comment: I think it would help if you told us what type of decking you plan to use and where you found this fastener.

Comment: details added. The planks will go perpendicular on the joists
The design is particular because I have vents on the house wall and this is a free standing deck

Comment: I've never seen that type of fastener but if you are running perpendicular than fastening to one side of every joist should be plenty strong.

Comment: I was thinking more from the perspective of wood to wood contact. These fasteners will raise the deck boards , especially if I put then on both sides of the joist
The fasteners are available at Home Depot Canada (Pylex is the manufacturer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [instruction sheet](http://www.grabberman.com/Deckmaster/HowToInstall.aspx) from Deckmaster has you installing on only one side, but alternating sides for interior joists, and adding extra bracket sections for decking splices.

I suggest that you follow manufacturer guidelines for your product.